# Validation error in email

Tags: javascript

Javascript Code

```
//more code
function change() {
    var select = document.getElementById("slct");
    var divv = document.getElementById("container");
    var value = select.value;
    var toAppend='';
    for(i = 0; i < value; i++)
    {
        toAppend += '<p class="profile-name">*Tracker</p><input type="text" data-validation-email-message="Not a valid email id!" pattern=  "^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)" data-validation-pattern-message="Must be a valid email id" requiredclass="input-medium" name="tracker[]" placeholder="Email Address" required="required"/>&nbsp; <input type="text"  pattern="^[0-9]{1,10}" data-validation-pattern-message="Do not use special characters or numbers" placeholder="Contact No" name="contact_tracker[]"/>';
    }
    divv.innerHTML = toAppend;  return;
}
//more code
```

HTML code

```
<select id="slct" onchange="change();">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">select</option>
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Here email is always giving error i.e it always give error given input field is correct as per the validation pattern

Comment: There is a large space between `pattern=` and your quotes around the pattern. Try removing that and see if the problem persists.

Comment: tried removing space and even changed quotes

Comment: @Class, I removed the tag

Comment: Can you use this pattern                  
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

Comment: the real regex you need to use is [this](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: error is not of regex as I have used this and its working in that but in javascript  it always show "Please match the requested format"       <input type="email" data-validation-email-message="Not a valid email id!" pattern=  "^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)" data-validation-pattern-message="Must be a valid email id" requiredclass="input-medium" name="email" required="required">

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong.Please use this

/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/

Comment: Still not working.I think error is somewhat of quotes.

Comment: Try my regex without both "/" (slashes). I have tried its working fine.

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+` does not mean 2-4 characters. Confusingly, it means repeat 2-4 characters, 1 or more times, which really means 2 or more characters with no upper limit.